# Difficulty in defining a higher-order function to mimic if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, higher-order-functions

I have been hard pressed to answer a question we were recently asked as part of an exercise on higher-order functions in Python.

The question is to define two functions, one which takes no arguments, and passes three globally defined functions, c(), t() and f(), through if/else statements (if `c()` true, return `t()` else return `f()`). The other function is a higher-order function that we evaluate on `c()`, `t()` and `f()` that then passes them through the same if/else statements.

These functions are different and our task is to see how by defining three functions `c()`, `t()` and `f()` such that the first function returns 1 and the second returns something other than one.

So far I have come to the realization that the issue lies with the calling of the functions `c()`, `t()` and `f()` before passing them through the if/else statements. This however has not been enough to inspire a solution. Would anyone be able to steer me in the correct direction?

Here is the associated code:

```
def if_function(condition, true_result, false_result):

    if condition:
        return true_result
else:
    return false_result


def with_if_statement():

    if c():
        return t()
    else:
        return f()

def with_if_function():

    return if_function(c(), t(), f())

def c():
    return []

def t():
    return 1

def f():
    return 1
```

Comment: I'm having trouble following the requirements.

Comment: It's unclear what a "no argument [function working on] global functions" would show (as then, why write a function at all?); also, what does "higher-order function [..] evaluated on" mean?

Comment: Could you please give some examples of usage of the functions and the expected out?

Answer (score 0):

You may easily pass callable as function arguments, without calling them.

```
def cond():
    return True

def f():
    return 2

def g():
    time.sleep(60)

def if_function(condition_callable, call_if_true, call_if_false):
    if condition_callable():
        return call_if_true()
    else:
        return call_if_false()

if_function(cond, f, g)  # evaluates immediately, does not sleep since g is never evaluated.
```